# Optimal number of moves for solving a puzzle

Tags: combinatorics

There is [this](http://chessboardifygame.xyz) puzzle game, where you are given a $3 \times 3$ grid which you should arrange in a specific way. From the page:

"You are given a coloured grid. The objective is to rearrange the colouring so that it forms a chessboard (every square has a different colour than any square it shares an edge with).

A tap on a square reverses the colour of the square and all of its neighbours (ones that share an edge or a vertex with the tapped square)."

Consider the optimal number of moves to solve any $3 \times 3$ configuration.

Some trivial facts:

1. The order of moves is irrelevant.
2. By (1.) the maximum number of moves can be at most 9.
3. Since the middle block only reverses the coloring, it is irrelevant. Thus the maximum number of moves is at most 8.

Is this bound sharp?

Comment: Your chessboard is changing everytime I reload the page...how do I tell you an answer?

Comment: The problem is "Consider the optimal number of moves to solve *any* $3 \times 3$ configuration" The game just illustrates the idea.

Comment: I solved a particular game in just *1* move...If your question is changing every time how do I provide you an algorithm to solve it?

Comment: Well is there a game that is not solvable in $1$ move? What about $2$ moves? What about $n$ moves? As explained above $n \leq 8$. Is the inequality actually strict?

Comment: Yes, $8$ is a sharp bound. The only solutions that require $8$ moves are the ones where every square is the same color except the center.